# Count of vertices of a subdivided triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

I need a formula to calculate the count of unique vertices for a subdivided triangle: $v = f(s)$ where $s$ is the count of subdivisions and $v$ is the count of vertices.

[image]

Let's take the biggest triangle in the picture. If I do not subdivide it I need $3$ vertices:
$f(0) = 3$

If I subdivide it once I need 6 vertices: $f(1) = 6$

I counted the vertices for the next subdivisions since I am not able to create a formula for it:

$$f(2) = 15\\
f(3) = 45\\
f(4) = 153$$

Can someone help me to find $f$?

Comment: If you look up [Triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) you will see that there is a simple formula.  If there is something more you wanted to know, please edit the Quesiton.

Comment: OEIS is your friend: [A028401](http://oeis.org/A028401)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, what you want is
$$f(n)=\left(2^n+1\right)\left(2^{n-1}+1\right)$$
If you're wondering how it is obtained, I suggest you to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: Thank you! This works well :)

Comment: @LucaHofmann. I'm happy it helped you. Please consider [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fa3b.png) option to help others find this answer useful too.